# Click the links according to index in List<WebElements> in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have page like this

Name age  operations

abc   12   remove

xyz   16   remove

remove is the link. I have to delete the row depending upon the name provided by the user.
My code is.

```
   int dynamicLinkIndex= -1;   

     public void getIndex(){
        List<WebElement> input = gui.getfWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath(xpathOfElement));

                for(WebElement web : input){
                    dynamicLinkIndex++;
                    if(web.getText().equals("abc"));
                        break;
                    }
                }

        }

        public void deleteElement(){
               WebElement web = input.get(dynamicLinkIndex).findElement(By.xpath(xpathOfElement))
        web.click();
        }
```

It is printing index properly.but always deleting the first element rather than following the index

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of counting indexes you should use xpath 'contains' function to get the 'abc' element and then get the proper sibling (remove button) of that element, all in one xpath. Example:

```
td[contains(text(),'abc')]/following-sibling::td[class='remove']
```

Comment: Maybe there's a scope problem since 'input' variable referred in deleteElement method is really declared in getIndex() method. Or maybe it's just that xpath is wrong. Imho your approach is bad practice it creates too much load and pointlessly uses much memory. You should try getting this element with one xpath.